# Shortcuts and mouse actions

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any mouse actions that cannot be made by a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Define mouse actions. If I took it to the extreme, I could say you could write (with your keyboard) a piece of code to move the mouse, make it double click or whatnot.

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What problem are you having that we can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

yes there are tons of "mouse actions" that cannot be performed with a keyboard shortcut.
   Try to draw with a keyboard shortcut.
 There are lots of programs in existance that do not have keyshorts for most of thier actions.
But in the windows systems
 There are very few things that cannot be operated in some way with "mouseKeys" , an accessibility (ease of access) option that turns the keypad into a joymouse. So a person can survive without a mouse (or touch) if they are desparate enough.